# Apache UserAgent Dependent Rewrite

Tags: apache

I am work on user agent redirection for downloads on a website, but keep getting error which I do not understand. It should download filetwo when android user agent is used.

```
  <Directory "/">
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
      Allow from all
      RewriteEngine On
      RedirectMatch ^/login$ /cgi-bin/login.html
 
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/download$
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^.*Android.*$"
      RewriteRule ^ "filetwo"
 
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/download$
      RewriteRule ^ "fileone"
  </Directory>
```

But when I request the download I only get fileone. If I remove the second RewriteCond then I can get it to work, but then I don't get the different files being served.